# Should questions directed solely to the IOTA Foundation be allowed?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

This is an example of such a question: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/are-there-any-other-deliberate-defects-in-the-iota-source-code-that-have-not-bee

EDIT: seems like OP deleted his question above. He was asking if there are any deliberate deficiencies left in IOTA's source code. This is a question that only a few IOTA Foundation members will be able to answer without speculating.